# Is it possible to get apns-collapse-id in the notification service extension?

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, unnotificationserviceextension

I am trying to access to the `apns-collapse-id` to change the content of the notification based on some conditions. Can the `apns-collapse-id` be accessed in the extension?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer pretty immediately after posting this.

`identifier` is the property you are looking for.

From the docs:

> Use this string to identify notifications in your app. For example,
> you can pass this string to the
> removePendingNotificationRequests(withIdentifiers:) method to cancel a
> previously scheduled notification. ...
>
> For local notifications, this property is set to the value passed to
> the request’s initializer (see the init(identifier:content:trigger:)
> method). For remote notifications, it is set to the value of the
> apns-collapse-id key that you specified in the APNs request header
> when generating the remote notification. If no value is set, the
> system automatically assigns an identifier.